# Javascript, AJAX and PHP Help

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, database

I have the following table in a MYSQL database:

```
Messages
MessageId (PK) int(10) - auto_inc
Message varchar(100)
```

I have the following PHP that echos a particular message:

```
<?php

//..connect to database
$query = "SELECT Message FROM Messages WHERE MessageId = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows( $result );
if ($num == 1){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo json_encode($row);
}else{
  echo('Invalid');
}

?>
```

Can anyone advise me on how best to integrate jQuery in order to allow the document browser window to write the response...

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. People don't generally write manual ajax code anymore, they use a library or framework like jQuery to help them. I'd start by researching jQuery.

Comment: Also, your PHP application should send appropriate headers (`Content-Type: application/json`) in order for these frameworks suggested by @Jonathan to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can easily use [jQuery.getJSON()<sup>*[DOCS]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) as follows:

```
$.getJSON('mypage.php', function(data) { 
   //Do somewith with JSON data
});
```

For normal Javascript, use

```
var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else//IE5, IE6
   xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.Status == 200)
   {
      var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      //Do something with JSON Data
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that link, Matt.  I was going to link to it, but couldn't find it.